# Realtime DB is not responding to requests | Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an website, that freezes upon executing a fetch when user becomes active (!documnet.hidden) and
the fetched data to the realtime DB do not execute for a get(query), and when using enableLogging(true) - the following is shown (image).

And then nothing else happens.

This is my method:

```
export async function getTargetRealDbData(
  path: string
): Promise < unknown > {
  console.log('getTargetRealDbData | START')

  const connectRef = ref(
    db_real
  );

  const data = await get(
      child(
        connectRef,
        path
      )
    )
    .then(
      (
        snapshot
      ) => {
        console.log('DATA OBTAINED!');
        if (snapshot.exists()) return snapshot.val();
        return null;
      }
    )
    .catch(
      (
        error
      ) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );

  console.log('getTargetRealDbData | END')

  return data;
}
```

`LOGS`

[image]

Why is this happening ?

This mainly to occurs on mobile / Safari, when the Safari's inactivity script shutdown kicks in.

I need to hard-refresh the website to get the data again.

I have tried all possible `logging` and `logical` JS changes, but the issue persists, and
the `get(query)` method simply `HANGS`.